# Internationalizaton of next.js website through subpath not working on sub-directories?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, next.js, server-side-rendering, ssg

I'm trying to internationalize my website through the subpath feature of next.js.

Here is my `module.export` :

```js
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'fr',
    locales: ['en', 'fr'],
  },
  react: {
    useSuspense: false,
    wait: true,
  },
}
```

Here is the structure of my `Page` folder:

```
.
│   404.js
│   about.js
│   blog.js
│   index.js
│   projects.js
│   tags.js
│   tree.txt
│   _app.js
│   _document.js
│   
└───blog
│   │   [...slug].js
│   │   
│   └───page
│           [page].js
│           
└───tags
        [tag].js
```

Everything works with subpath when I'm in the root page directories. `localhost:3000/about`, `localhost:3000/en/about` works. `localhost:3000/fr/about` redirect as `localhost:3000/about` as intended.

But when I try to access a statically generated page in a folder, in the `en` subpath (like `localhost:3000/en/blog/article1` for example, I get a 404.

How can I make sure the site statically generates pages also for the `en` subpath ?

Comment: Can you show us what does your `/blog/[...slug].js` file look like? Specifically the `getStaticPaths`/`getStaticProps` functions.

Comment: Thank you ! It was indeed that.

For everyone going by that post,  you need to generate a page for each local. It means getting the `locales` prop, which is the list of the different local, and adding them to the return of the `getStaticPaths({locales})`.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, it was because next, in SSR, generated a page only for the root `/`, and not for the different locals ( `/fr/` for example).

I had to change the `getStaticPaths()` as follow to correct it:

```
export async function getStaticPaths({ locales }: { locales: any }) {
  const tags = await getAllTags('blog')

  const path = (locale) =>
    Object.keys(tags).map((tag) => ({
      params: {
        tag,
      },
      locale,
    }))
  const paths = locales.map((locale) => path(locale)).flat()

  return {
    paths: paths,
    fallback: false,
  }
}
```